# Cannot get ffmpeg to work after installing from homebrew

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, homebrew

I installed ffmpeg through homebrew but when I try to run it, even just typing in `ffmpeg` I get the following error message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've tried running `brew update` and `brew upgrade` but that didn't change anything. Running `brew doctor` the only error I get is:

```
Warning: You have a curlrc file
If you have trouble downloading packages with Homebrew, then maybe this
is the problem? If the following command doesn't work, then try removing
your curlrc:
  curl http://github.com
```

New at doing things in the terminal, what to do next?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I got it to work by running `brew search liblzma` which told me `lzma is now part of the xz formula.`

So then I ran `brew install xz` and tried running `ffmpeg` again and it works now!

Comment: A note, `brew install xz` took a few hours (and did not fix it).

Comment: in my case its print `➜  Movies brew search libtesseract
==> Formulae
tesseract ✔` thats mean alr installed but the error is same , not loaded . m1 apple sillicon

Answer (score 6):

## What Worked Today

I'm running OSX Mojave 10.14.5 and got the `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib` complaint.

- `brew install xz` did not work
- Reinstall worked like a boss

```
brew uninstall --force ffmpeg && brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: I had an error: `Error: ffmpeg: no bottle available!` and had to do a `brew install --build-from-source ffmpeg`