# passenger meet Library not loaded error : liblzma.5.dylib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, homebrew, aws-sdk

I am trying to running rails with passenger.

I both AWS SDK 1 and 2 gem installed:

```
gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
```

when I use AWS sdk to run:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
```

I meet error:

```
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/XXXX/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/XXXX/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 8.0.0 or later, but liblzma.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

otool -L  shows me that the version is 8.1.0

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
/usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib:
/usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

It is strange that this error not shows up when I run 'rails s'.
update / uninstall / reinstall  xz by brew  not helps.
update / uninstall / reinstall gem nokogiri also not helps.

Comment: could you accept my response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to follow this https://github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar/issues/530#issuecomment-125746641

This is the fix: [Cannot get ffmpeg to work after installing from homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612086/cannot-get-ffmpeg-to-work-after-installing-from-homebrew)

Using brew: `brew install xz` because `liblzma` is inside `xz` now

Comment: I had this issue with the Nogokiri gem in my Rails app. Your command also worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a problem in Passenger, it is a problem in one of your gems. Apparently you installed Nokogiri some time in the past, and back then it was linked to liblzma 5, but some time later you upgraded liblzma to the incompatible version 6. Try uninstalling that gem, then installing it again.

Comment: as I said  ,  update / uninstall / reinstall gem nokogiri also not helps.
and why "rails s"   is working but passanger not working ? they should refer to the same gem folder and file right?
and I have check the version /usr/local/lib/liblzma.5.dylib is 8.0.1
if I need to uninstall gem,  which gem should I uninstall and how to find it?
I have tried my best on internet to investigate this issue. no clue to know how to track back the issued file

Comment: Maybe because of environment variable differences? Try Passenger Standalone (run `passenger start`) instead of Passenger for Nginx or Passenger for Apache.

Comment: I am using apache2  here is my setting, it is in development env.
 loadModule passenger_module /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
    PassengerUser XXXX
    PassengerRoot /usr/local/opt/passenger/libexec/lib/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
    PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/XXXX/.rbenv/shims/ruby
  <Directory />
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
                RailsEnv development
 </Directory>

Comment: I just try   passenger start ad my project folder,  it is works well!
but I still need it running with apache2.  

so question is back ,  why my apache2 setting is not working ?  the user and env is the same ,  what I missing...

Comment: so  seems  I need to know how to check passenger statues in both  condition?

Comment: I check status with passenger-status:
aVhb9dkM                   nginx/1.8.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.15
36mXhnSk                   Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.15
the Apache one is not working,   nginx is the one running from project folder

Answer (score 0):

updating gems worked for me

```
bundle update
```

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful to future readers if you explained *why* it might have worked for you when the gem uninstall/reinstall process detailed by the OP didn't work.