# Import Error while load rpy2 in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook (MAC OSX)

Tags: python, r, macos, anaconda, rpy2

I am using jupyter notebook in Anaconda to load rpy2 in python.

Import Error while load rpy2 in Anaconda Jupyter Notebook (MAC OSX)

```
    %load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Here are the errors I get:

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> ```
>
> last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 get_ipython().magic('load_ext rpy2.ipython')
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py
>   in magic(self, arg_s)    2156         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s =
>   arg_s.partition(' ')    2157         magic_name =
>   magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
>   -> 2158         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)    2159     2160
>
> ## -------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py
>   in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)    2077
>   kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals    2078
>   with self.builtin_trap:
>   -> 2079                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)    2080             return result    2081
>
> in load_ext(self, module_str)
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py
>   in (f, *a, **k)
>       186     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
>       187     def magic_deco(arg):
>   --> 188         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
>       189 
>       190         if callable(arg):
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/extension.py
>   in load_ext(self, module_str)
>        35         if not module_str:
>        36             raise UsageError('Missing module name.')
>   ---> 37         res = self.shell.extension_manager.load_extension(module_str)
>        38 
>        39         if res == 'already loaded':
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/extensions.py
>   in load_extension(self, module_str)
>        81             if module_str not in sys.modules:
>        82                 with prepended_to_syspath(self.ipython_extension_dir):
>   ---> 83                     **import**(module_str)
>        84             mod = sys.modules[module_str]
>        85             if self._call_load_ipython_extension(mod):
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/**init**.py
>   in ()
>   ----> 1 from .rmagic import load_ipython_extension
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/ipython/rmagic.py
>   in ()
>        51 # numpy and rpy2 imports
>        52 
>   ---> 53 import rpy2.rinterface as ri
>        54 import rpy2.robjects as ro
>        55 import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpacks
>
> /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py
>   in ()
>        48 del(os)
>        49 
>   ---> 50 from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
>        51                                          emptyenv,
>        52                                          endr,
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libiconv.2.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/carrielin/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Reason: Incompatible library version:
>   _rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 8.0.0

I haven't searched other answers for this problem and am waiting for your help.

Could someone help me resolve the above errors?

Comment: I think that this is an issue discussed on anaconda's issue tracker: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6395

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's for a different problem, the fix from this post worked for me: [passenger meet Library not loaded error : liblzma.5.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293619/passenger-meet-library-not-loaded-error-liblzma-5-dylib)

Simply `brew install xz` in terminal. If you don't have brew, you can get it here: https://brew.sh/